# What is the right way of containing data in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm rebuilding school project from html page to django app. In old project I had some articles and two tests. 
For articles I created django model with text field and pasted in it article's content with HTML due to it have some decorations as a <"code> <"/code> tags.

How should I contain tests if first is build with HTML forms and second with <"canvas>? Should I use text field again? Data is too complex. For the first test it goes as a forms with individual texts and inputs and checked by javascript. For second it is initializing js functions.

How they are look like:

> First test with forms

[image: First test with forms]

> Second test with canvas

[image: Second test with canvas]

Where can I read about it more? 

P.S. Sorry for bad english

Comment: What do you mean by "test"? Are you talking about unit tests? And then with that, what do you mean by "contain test"?

Comment: Yes, about unit tests. Is it better to call them tasks? If so, now I have two types of tasks and for each of them i have different data to contain. I just want to know if is it normal to use text field. Like if I just paste HTML forms and inputs in it.

Comment: No test is fine, just clarify that it's unit test at the beginning. Also, what's containing the data? And what are you pasting HTML forms and inputs into? What is "it"? the unit test or the form? or the data? Please break down your problem more.

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick 1. The only solution that I see now to move unit tests (tests that you can see on pictures) form my old project to Django app is to use text field and contain tests data in it like I done with articles. 2. How I want it to work: a). I have url paths ../practice - to display the test list and ../practice/<int: pk> to display test by itself b). For this tests I have model with type field and content field. c). DetailView for tests will grab content from tests model and render the page with test. 3. So the question is: Is it the right way to use text field to contain this data?

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick I'm doing my best to describe the problem. I hope that now it is clear. If not please ask again